# Strange behavior on a value assignment in a loop in python

Tags: python

This is my first question in Stack Overflow (be kind….hahah).

> After some comments I decided to simplify the question.

I have a function that takes the following inputs.

```
toProcessData = {'STUDENTID': 'datasource.id',
                 'NAME': 'datasource.name',
                 'ADDRESS': 'datasource.address',
                 'STATE': 'datasource.state'}
dataSource = {'datasource.id':'1231231',
              'datasource.name':'John Smith'}
```

The function should produce a new dictionary according to the following rules.

- If the Value of an element in toProcessData exist as a key in dataSource, such as in the case of the first two elements in the example (STUDENTID, NAME). The output should be a new dictionary element of the form:

  `{toProcessData[key]:dataSource[value]}`
- If the Value of an element in toProcessData is not found as a key in dataSource, like the case of the last two elements in the example (ADDRESS, STATE). The output should be a new dictionary element of the form:

  `{toProcessData[key]:{'NO_DATA_AVAILABLE_AT':toProcessData[value]}}`

When I write the function like this:

```
def processData (toProcessData, dataSource):
    noDataDescription = {'NO_DATA_AVAILABLE_AT':""}
    extractedElements = {}
    for element in toProcessData.items():
        elementValue = element[1]
        elementKey = element[0]
        if elementValue in list(dataSource.keys()):
            extractedElements[elementKey] = dataSource[elementValue]
        else:                
            extractedElements[elementKey] = noDataDescription
            extractedElements[elementKey]['NO_DATA_AVAILABLE_AT'] = elementValue
    return extractedElements
```

The output looks like this:

```
{'STUDENTID': '1231231',
 'NAME': 'John Smith',
 'ADDRESS': {'NO_DATA_AVAILABLE_AT': 'datasource.state'},
 'STATE': {'NO_DATA_AVAILABLE_AT': 'datasource.state'}}
```

The key ADDRESS is matched with datasource.state and not datasource.address, as it should be.

However, when I write the function like this:

```
def processData01 (toProcessData, dataSource):
    extractedElements = {}
    for element in toProcessData.items():
        elementValue = element[1]
        elementKey = element[0]
        if elementValue in list(dataSource.keys()):
            extractedElements[elementKey] = dataSource[elementValue]
        else:                
            extractedElements[elementKey] = {'NO_DATA_AVAILABLE_AT':elementValue}
    return extractedElements
```

The output looks correct.

```
{'STUDENTID': '1231231',
 'NAME': 'John Smith',
 'ADDRESS': {'NO_DATA_AVAILABLE_AT': 'datasource.address'},
 'STATE': {'NO_DATA_AVAILABLE_AT': 'datasource.state'}}
```

I think the logic in both versions is the same, just wondering what causes the strange behavior in the first version of the function.

Comment: Your question is too vague and difficult to follow. Cut it down to a smaller focussed query.

Comment: Really hard to follow. At any rate, provide the sample datasource which generates the exceptions.

Comment: This happens because when you do `extractedElements[elementKey] = noDataDescription` it doesn't create a copy of the `noDataDescription` dictionary, it causes `extractedElements[elementKey]` to point to the same dictionary the variable `noDataDescription` points to. So then when you modify it with `extractedElements[elementKey]['NO_DATA_AVAILABLE_AT'] = elementValue` you are actually modifying the `noDataDescription` dictionary. You have to create a copy `from copy import deepcopy` and then `extractedElements[elementKey] = deepcopy(noDataDescription)`

Comment: Also, Python is not a `camelCase` language. Variable and function names [should be named `lowercase_with_underscores`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names).